# Problems converting CoinMarketCap API json data into flattened pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, coinmarketcap

**Goal**
I'm successfully importing CMC data from the APi into nested JSON, per this example:
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest

**Working API Call**

```
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'

parameters = { 
              'id': '2280,4558,5221,1518,7653,5026,10688,5632,5567,5692,5566,8075,7083', 
              'convert': 'USD' 
              } 

headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': CMC_AUTH
        } 

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
data = json.loads(response.text)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

**Result**

That returns the nested JSON as in the example above, with slightly different data that hasn't been updated in the documentation example.

This is the first `id` returned for the code above:

```
{'data': {'10688': {'circulating_supply': 116331159.1611021,
                    'cmc_rank': 347,
                    'date_added': '2021-06-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                    'id': 10688,
                    'is_active': 1,
                    'is_fiat': 0,
                    'last_updated': '2022-09-05T19:20:00.000Z',
                    'max_supply': 1000000000,
                    'name': 'Yield Guild Games',
                    'num_market_pairs': 98,
                    'platform': {'id': 1027,
                                 'name': 'Ethereum',
                                 'slug': 'ethereum',
                                 'symbol': 'ETH',
                                 'token_address': '0x25f8087ead173b73d6e8b84329989a8eea16cf73'},
                    'quote': {'USD': {'fully_diluted_market_cap': 482405830.29,
                                      'last_updated': '2022-09-05T19:20:00.000Z',
                                      'market_cap': 56118829.42337308,
                                      'market_cap_dominance': 0.0057,
                                      'percent_change_1h': 0.43811262,
                                      'percent_change_24h': -3.21631892,
                                      'percent_change_30d': -40.69530618,
                                      'percent_change_60d': -32.68437619,
                                      'percent_change_7d': -8.8136777,
                                      'percent_change_90d': -16.90500242,
                                      'price': 0.48240583028710726,
                                      'tvl': None,
                                      'volume_24h': 11205334.0356885,
                                      'volume_change_24h': -48.174}},
                    'self_reported_circulating_supply': 87906250,
                    'self_reported_market_cap': 42406487.51867602,
                    'slug': 'yield-guild-games',
                    'symbol': 'YGG',
                    'tags': [{'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'Collectibles & NFTs',
                              'slug': 'collectibles-nfts'},
                             {'category': 'INDUSTRY',
                              'name': 'Gaming',
                              'slug': 'gaming'},
                             {'category': 'INDUSTRY',
                              'name': 'Entertainment',
                              'slug': 'entertainment'},
                             {'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'DAO',
                              'slug': 'dao'},
                             {'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'Metaverse',
                              'slug': 'metaverse'},
                             {'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'a16z Portfolio',
                              'slug': 'a16z-portfolio'},
                             {'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'Play To Earn',
                              'slug': 'play-to-earn'},
                             {'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'Animoca Brands Portfolio',
                              'slug': 'animoca-brands-portfolio'},
                             {'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'Gaming Guild',
                              'slug': 'gaming-guild'},
                             {'category': 'CATEGORY',
                              'name': 'OKEx Blockdream Ventures Portfolio',
                              'slug': 'okex-blockdream-ventures-portfolio'}],
                    'total_supply': 1000000000,
                    'tvl_ratio': None},
```

I'm now wanting to flatten the json data and convert it to a pandas dataframe, so I've changed the last line of the above to:

**Alternate code**

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
pprint.pprint(df)
```

**Result**

That produces a single row with 454 columns, versus a dataframe with rows for all 13 of the id's I've specified and the corresponding column values.

From what I've read, json_normalize should be the way to flatten the data, and I'm thinking the issue is specifying that I want the nested `quote` data flattened and I should probably remove the nested `tags` list of dictionaries, but I'm not finding any information on how to do that.

I've tried adding the `record_path` parameter to `json_normalize` for `quote`, but that just returns `KeyError: 'quote'`.

I'm not finding any additional information for troubleshooting this, and would greatly appreciate any guidance in how to approach this.

**AMENDED CODE**

**New Version**

```
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'

parameters = { 
              'id': '2280,4558',
              'convert': 'USD'
              } 

headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': CMC_AUTH
        } 

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
data = json.loads(response.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"]).T.explode("tags")
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("platform").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("platform_")], axis=1
    )
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("quote").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("quote_")], axis=1
    )
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("tags").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("tag_")], axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Result**

I'm wanting to also have the `quote_USD` data in columns and values for the key:value pairs, and could drop the `tags` data if that simplifies it considerably.

```
       id      name symbol      slug num_market_pairs  \
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
2280  2280  Filecoin    FIL  filecoin              241   
4558  4558      Flow   FLOW      flow               87   
4558  4558      Flow   FLOW      flow               87   
4558  4558      Flow   FLOW      flow               87   
4558  4558      Flow   FLOW      flow               87   
4558  4558      Flow   FLOW      flow               87   
4558  4558      Flow   FLOW      flow               87   
4558  4558      Flow   FLOW      flow               87   

                    date_added max_supply circulating_supply total_supply  \
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
2280  2017-12-13T00:00:00.000Z       None          275966217    275966217   
4558  2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z       None         1036200000   1390757889   
4558  2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z       None         1036200000   1390757889   
4558  2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z       None         1036200000   1390757889   
4558  2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z       None         1036200000   1390757889   
4558  2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z       None         1036200000   1390757889   
4558  2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z       None         1036200000   1390757889   
4558  2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z       None         1036200000   1390757889   

     is_active cmc_rank is_fiat self_reported_circulating_supply  \
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
2280         1       34       0                             None   
4558         1       31       0                             None   
4558         1       31       0                             None   
4558         1       31       0                             None   
4558         1       31       0                             None   
4558         1       31       0                             None   
4558         1       31       0                             None   
4558         1       31       0                             None   

     self_reported_market_cap tvl_ratio              last_updated  \
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
2280                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
4558                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
4558                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
4558                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
4558                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
4558                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
4558                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   
4558                     None      None  2022-09-06T02:31:00.000Z   

                                              quote_USD  \
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
2280  {'price': 6.094999087542264, 'volume_24h': 209...   
4558  {'price': 1.9051178692194919, 'volume_24h': 47...   
4558  {'price': 1.9051178692194919, 'volume_24h': 47...   
4558  {'price': 1.9051178692194919, 'volume_24h': 47...   
4558  {'price': 1.9051178692194919, 'volume_24h': 47...   
4558  {'price': 1.9051178692194919, 'volume_24h': 47...   
4558  {'price': 1.9051178692194919, 'volume_24h': 47...   
4558  {'price': 1.9051178692194919, 'volume_24h': 47...   

                          tag_slug                      tag_name tag_category  
2280                      mineable                      Mineable       OTHERS  
2280         distributed-computing         Distributed Computing     INDUSTRY  
2280                   filesharing                   Filesharing     INDUSTRY  
2280                       storage                       Storage     CATEGORY  
2280   polychain-capital-portfolio   Polychain Capital Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280  blockchain-capital-portfolio  Blockchain Capital Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280             boostvc-portfolio             BoostVC Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280                 dcg-portfolio                 DCG Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280     hashkey-capital-portfolio     Hashkey Capital Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280                a16z-portfolio                a16z Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280  winklevoss-capital-portfolio  Winklevoss Capital Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280     pantera-capital-portfolio     Pantera Capital Portfolio     CATEGORY  
2280                          web3                          Web3     INDUSTRY  
2280                     bnb-chain                     BNB Chain     PLATFORM  
4558             collectibles-nfts           Collectibles & NFTs     CATEGORY  
4558   coinbase-ventures-portfolio   Coinbase Ventures Portfolio     CATEGORY  
4558            coinfund-portfolio            Coinfund Portfolio     CATEGORY  
4558                 dcg-portfolio                 DCG Portfolio     CATEGORY  
4558         ledgerprime-portfolio         LedgerPrime Portfolio     CATEGORY  
4558                a16z-portfolio                a16z Portfolio     CATEGORY  
4558      animoca-brands-portfolio      Animoca Brands Portfolio     CATEGORY  
\n#pprint.pprint(data)\n\n#df = pd.json_normalize(data)\ndf = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['quote'])\npprint.pprint(df)\n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to flatten the dataframe loaded from the Json from the question (`dct` contains the dictionary):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"]).T
df = df.drop(columns="tags")

df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("platform").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("platform_")], axis=1
)
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("quote").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("quote_")], axis=1
)
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("quote_USD").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("quote_USD_")], axis=1
)


print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      circulating_supply cmc_rank                date_added     id is_active is_fiat              last_updated  max_supply               name num_market_pairs self_reported_circulating_supply self_reported_market_cap               slug symbol total_supply tvl_ratio  platform_id platform_name platform_slug platform_symbol                      platform_token_address  quote_USD_fully_diluted_market_cap    quote_USD_last_updated  quote_USD_market_cap  quote_USD_market_cap_dominance  quote_USD_percent_change_1h  quote_USD_percent_change_24h  quote_USD_percent_change_30d  quote_USD_percent_change_60d  quote_USD_percent_change_7d  quote_USD_percent_change_90d  quote_USD_price quote_USD_tvl  quote_USD_volume_24h  quote_USD_volume_change_24h
10688   116331159.161102      347  2021-06-28T00:00:00.000Z  10688         1       0  2022-09-05T19:20:00.000Z  1000000000  Yield Guild Games               98                         87906250          42406487.518676  yield-guild-games    YGG   1000000000      None         1027      Ethereum      ethereum             ETH  0x25f8087ead173b73d6e8b84329989a8eea16cf73                        4.824058e+08  2022-09-05T19:20:00.000Z          5.611883e+07                          0.0057                     0.438113                     -3.216319                    -40.695306                    -32.684376                    -8.813678                    -16.905002         0.482406          None          1.120533e+07                      -48.174
```

Comment: @Andrej_Kesely thank you for the input. My results came out differently, and I think it's because I don't understand what to put in place of `dct` in your code example. Of the Dictionaries in the data, the only one that worked was 'data', but as that's already used in `['data']`, my presumption is that isn't right. Also, I'm mainly interested in the `quote_USD` data, and having that in columns and rows for the key:value dictionary pairs. I could drop the `tags` data to simplify things. I've added an **AMENDED CODE** section above to hopefully clarify what I'm seeing.